# each function for jquery calculations

Tags: jquery, list, each

Here is a link to the codepen: [to the codepen](https://codepen.io/Nyqvist/pen/pZRqRK?editors=1010) --> note: you have to change one of the 2 values to see a result.

I have 2 fixed vars (var seiten and var monate) and up to 12 * 3 "dynamic" vars Starter1, KRW1, KPreis1 each from 1 tp 12 (I added 5 for testing). The calculation works so far, but only for the first item. I don`t know how i could use a each function for those.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function compute() {
      var seiten = $('#seiten').val();
      var monate = $('#monate').val();

      var Starter1 = $('#Starter1').val();
      var KRW1 = $('#KRW1').val();
      var KPreis1 = $('#KPreis1').val();

      var Starter2 = $('#Starter2').val();
      var KRW2 = $('#KRW2').val();
      var KPreis2 = $('#KPreis2').val();

      var Starter3 = $('#Starter3').val();
      var KRW3 = $('#KRW3').val();
      var KPreis3 = $('#KPreis3').val();

      var Starter4 = $('#Starter4').val();
      var KRW4 = $('#KRW4').val();
      var KPreis4 = $('#KPreis4').val();

      var Starter5 = $('#Starter5').val();
      var KRW5 = $('#KRW5').val();
      var KPreis5 = $('#KPreis5').val();

      var total1 = (((seiten * monate - Starter1) / KRW1) * KPreis1);
      var total2 = (((seiten * monate - Starter2) / KRW2) * KPreis2);
      var total3 = (((seiten * monate - Starter3) / KRW3) * KPreis3);
      var total4 = (((seiten * monate - Starter4) / KRW4) * KPreis4);
      var total5 = (((seiten * monate - Starter5) / KRW5) * KPreis5);



      if(total1 < 0 || total1 == null) { total1 == 0 ; } else { total1; }
      if(total2 < 0 || total2 == null) { total2 == 0 ; } else { total2; }
      if(total3 < 0 || total3 == null) { total3 == 0 ; } else { total3; }
      if(total4 < 0 || total4 == null) { total4 == 0 ; } else { total4; }
      if(total5 < 0 || total5 == null) { total5 == 0 ; } else { total5; }


      var total = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5;
      if(total < 0 || total == null) { total == 0 ; } else { total ; }


      $('#total').text(total);
    }

    $('#seiten, #monate').change(compute);

  ;
```

});

Comment: I'm not sure about the other items... Not sure what you mean. What I can tell is your 5 `if` statements are strange. If less than 0 or null, `totaln==0` **but** else... does nothing. -- It looks like a math/logic problem more than coding.

Comment: That logic worked pretty fine- even before. As it makes no sense for my calculations that totaln is -x so instead it should be 0. If it`s not negative it should be totaln.... total1 == null is just some kind of insurance...

Comment: Ok... But, what I say is that you can totally remove all `else`... And it will also work since the else parts does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each item in it's own container so you can loop over each of those.

Then instead of using ID you can use classes and you can have the same classes in each item. That makes them standard.

Once they are similar structure you use `find()` within each instance

---

Simplified version:

```js
function compute() {
  var seiten = $('#seiten').val();
  var monate = $('#monate').val();

  $('.item').each(function() {
    var $item = $(this)
    var Starter = $item.find('.Starter').val();
    var KRW = $item.find('.KRW').val();

    var total = seiten * Starter + monate * KRW;
    $item.find('.total').text(total);
  });
}

$('#seiten, #monate').change(compute);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="seiten">Seiten:</label>
  <input type="number" name="seiten" id="seiten" value="10" />

  <label for="monate">Monate:</label>
  <input type="number" name="monate" id="monate" value="10" />

  <!-- ITEM 1-->

  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <input type="hidden" class="Starter" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="KRW1" class="KRW" value="2" />
    <div class="total"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <input type="hidden" class="Starter" value="20" />
    <input type="hidden" class="KRW" value="20" />
    <div class="total"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That works pretty flawless - as long as there are no 0´s involved. 
And as i mentioned above, since totaln should be 0 when being negative this if else command is necessary.

Comment: if(total1 <= 0 || isNaN(total1)) { total1 == 0 ; } else { total1; }

I added isNaN instead of == null and it works perfectly. Well yeah... you see I`m new to Javascript / jQuery... THANKS a lot